# Do dependency versions affect substitution of included builds in a Gradle composite build?

Tags: gradle, build, dependencies

#### Context

I have one project (A) that depends on another (B), both using the Gradle build system. Project A usually declares a dependency on a specific version of B. When modifying project B, it's convenient to immediately see the effects on project A. Using `includeBuild` in `settings.gradle` or `--include-build` on the command line, the build of project A is reconfigured to include the local development version of project B instead of a published artifact (a "composite build"). However, this local copy of project B declares a development version number, not the stable release version requested by project A. To ensure that the included build of B satisfies the declared dependency in A, I have been changing A to request a version range like `org.example:B:[v6, )` instead of `org.example:B:v6.0`. However, I see that the build succeeds even when A specifies nonsensical version numbers that do not correspond to B.

#### Question

How do versions affect this dependency substitution process?

#### Research

The documentation I have read (linked below) shows how to include a build, but does not mention version numbers.
https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_composite_builds_basics.html
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html#defining_composite_builds

Some hints may be present on [this page](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/resolution_rules.html#sec:dependency_substitution_rules) covering "brute force" modifications of dependency resolution:

> In composite builds, the rule that you have to match the exact
> requested dependency attributes is not applied: when using composites,
> Gradle will automatically match the requested attributes. In other
> words, it is implicit that if you include another build, you are
> substituting all variants of the substituted module with an equivalent
> variant in the included build.

Although this deals with "variants" and their "attributes", which according to the [dependency terminology documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management_terminology.html) seem to be distinct from module versioning, the statement seems related. Can something similar be said about dependency module versions?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer: Most likely not... ?

On [this page](https://docs.gradle.org/8.2/userguide/composite_builds.html#included_build_declaring_substitutions) it is written (emphasize mine):

> Gradle will inspect the **group and name** for the projects in the included build, and substitute project dependencies for any external dependency matching ${project.group}:${project.name}.

And similarly, on [this page](https://docs.gradle.org/8.2/samples/sample_composite_builds_declared_substitutions.html) (emphasize mine):

> Gradle will inspect the **group and name** for the projects in the included build, and substitute project dependencies for any matching external dependency.

These are the only quotes on the topic I could find, which unfortunately are vague. What we can tell is that *substitution* goes with *group and name*, and the word *version* is not mentioned. Indeed, as both you and I have empirically tested, we know that specifying the version has no relevance whatsoever.

#### We don't want the version to matter.

Thinking about this  It kind of makes sense. The substitution is from a local source — implicitly then, the ever evolving developer version, or a patched one. But certainly not from a binary release.

And this was really, our conscious choice. Because we specified the substitute with our include-local-build directive, and we get exactly what we asked for. If we want the version to matter, then we don't substitute and voila, Gradle will have to go out and get the versioned binary release.

#### And it will never matter.

Taking this one step further — could Gradle even work differently? I am doubtful. Because the version specified in the source code is inherently unreliable. Would this be the version we last built and released, or is it the next version we plan to release? Maybe Gradle should be able to keep track of local file system changes, and heuristically validate versions, somehow!

The only mapping from version to actual source code is Git tagging. Which opens the door to loads of complexities ⚠️